# 500 Server Error ReWrite htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule home$/project1/index.php
```

Is there something missing in this code?
i tried to rewrite my url but it giving me 500 error

Comment: I don't think this question belongs to SO. See this thread : http://serverfault.com/questions/111279/internal-server-500-error on SF. Maybe you are missing a forward slash at the begining of your `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of wrong syntax in this rule:

```
RewriteRule home$/project1/index.php
```

Right syntax is:

```
RewriteRule matching-pattern target-uri [flags]?
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)